# What is the best way to define a constant in an Angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, constants

I currently put my constants on the $scope. I don't feel like this is the best way to do it as anyone can access the scope with their JS console.

What is the best method to define constants in Angular?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('calculatorController', function($scope) {
    $scope.values = [];

    $scope.CONSTANTS = {
        ERROR_MESSAGES: {
            NOT_INTEGER: "One of the values input was not a number!"
        }
    };

    $scope.add = function () {
        var calculatedValue = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.values; i++) {
            if (typeof $scope.values[i] === 'string' || $scope.values[i] instanceof String) {
                alert($scope.CONSTANTS.ERROR_MESSAGES.NOT_INTEGER);
            }

            calculatedValue += $scope.values[i];
        }
        return calculatedValue;
    }
});
```

Comment: refer https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it a variable within the `controller` callback (or a `const` if using TypeScript or ES2015+ JavaScript):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('calculatorController', function($scope) {
    var ERROR_MESSAGES = {
        NOT_INTEGER: "One of the values input was not a number!"
    };

    $scope.values = [];

    $scope.add = function () {
        var calculatedValue = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.values; i++) {
            if (typeof $scope.values[i] === 'string' || $scope.values[i] instanceof String) {
                alert(ERROR_MESSAGES.NOT_INTEGER);
            }

            calculatedValue += $scope.values[i];
        }
        return calculatedValue;
    }
});
```

(Though that *particular* kind of constant should probably be loaded from somewhere...)

Comment: Ahh, that makes perfect sense, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the constants at one place, another way is to declare constants as below .

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
  angular.module('AppName').constant('versionConstant', { 
       "versionNum":"1.22"
   });

  // And inject them in your  controller

  angular.module(AppName).controller(ControllerName, ['$scope','versionConstant', 
    function ($scope, versionConstant) {
         var version=versionConstant.versionNum;
    });
```

Comment: That is very userful, does this mean I can inject my constants as a dependency?

Comment: Yes, you can inject constants as dependency in your controller.